# Can't prevent submit on dynamically inserted <button> into DOM, that is part of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really strange issue, that seems very basic but I can't get it to work. 
I can't prevent the submit event of the button, that is dynamically instered into a div that is also part of a form.

Markup

```
 <form>
   ...
   <div class="dynamically-inserted">
     <button class="copy-inquiry">Copy</button>
   </div>
   ...
   <button id="submit-form" type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

jQuery

```
 $( "body" ).on( "click", ".copy-inquiry", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("button clicked");
 });
```

On click the form submits and the `console.log("button clicked")` doesn't get printed. If I add `type="button` then the form doesn't submit but still nothing happens.

Thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide `id='frm'` to the form

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/hfyfmcju/)  for further explanation

Html

```
<form id="frm">
  <button type="submit" class="btn1">ss1</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn2">ss2</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn3">ss3</button>
</form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#frm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val=$(this).find("button[type=submit]:focus").attr("class");/* this selects the class of button which trigger submit event */
    alert(val)
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This helps, but the problem is that beside having the `<button class="copy-inquiry">` I also insert some other buttons like `<button class="edit-inquiry">`. How do I know which button triggered it so I can perform different actions for each?

Comment: submit is triggered by submit button only

Comment: In my example, every button is triggering the submit.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to change `body` to `document`.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was apparently really simple. Change the `body` to `document` like this.

```
 $( "document" ).on( "click", ".copy-inquiry", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("button clicked");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle** **https://jsfiddle.net/rj1405/jaordzuy/2/**

You can also use **`<input>` tag** instead of **`<submit`**.

**Please check the JSFidller The bellow code is not working in Stackoverflow**

as given in the following example.

```js
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('submit button')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" class="btn1"/>
  <input type="button" class="btn2" value= "btn2"/>
  <input type="button" class="btn3" value= "btn3"/>
</form>
```